# How to solve this 'character not allowed in prolog' error in my CSS file

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I have the property declaration `h3 {color:#333;}` in my CSS file. When I check my CSS file in https://validator.w3.org, it shows

> character "h" not allowed in prolog.

What's the problem with my h3 tag? What is the meaning of "prolog"? Can someone explain it?

Comment: Show us more. Post the contents of your CSS file? Or at least part of it.

Answer (score 9):

https://validator.w3.org/ is for validating HTML only.

You are looking for http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

For CSS check in this https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ instead of this https://validator.w3.org/